# Is there a good way to structure my test code so I don't have to duplicate tests for different browsers using WatiN

Tags: automated-testing, watin

In my WatiN tests I am currently structuring the test like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Failed_Attempted_Login_Invalid_Combination()
{
    using (var browser = new IE(baseUrl + "login.aspx"))
    {
        browser.Page<AVLoginPage>().Login("test@roger.com", "123421343414");

        Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("Email address or password is incorrect. "));

    }
}
```

Is there a clean way to be able to specify the browser without having to create separate tests for each browser type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Factory method that return an object instance of type Browser.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {

        public static Browser BrowserFactory(bool IWantToUseIEAndOnlyIE)
        {
            Browser result;
            if (IWantToUseIEAndOnlyIE)
            {
                result = new IE();
            }
            else {
                result = new FireFox();
            }

            return result;
        }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Browser b = BrowserFactory(true))
            {
                b.GoTo("http://sqa.stackexchange.com/");
                b.WaitForComplete(20*10000);
                b.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```